# How to limit @ModelAttribute from being called on certain urls

Tags: spring, spring-mvc, controller

I'm having trouble to restrain `@ModelAttribute` from being called on some urls like static resources found on my pages. This results in about 50% of the calls to these methods redundant.

I tried to restrict `@ModelAttribute` with `@GetMapping`, creating multiple methods to filter the urls. All without a major success.

GlobalController.java

```
@ControllerAdvice
public class GlobalControllerAdvice {

    public static int k;

    @Autowired
    private UsersService usersService;

    @ModelAttribute("unread")
    public int unread(Principal principal) {

        int unread = 0;

        k++;
        System.err.println("Inside unread " + k);

        if (principal != null) {
            User user = usersService.getWithUser(principal.getName(), "notifications");
            for (Notification n : user.getNotifications())
                if (!n.isRead())
                    unread++;
        }

        return unread;
    }
}
```

`featured.jsp` (example of code that redundantly calls unread, the `@ModelAttribute` method.)

```
    <img alt="genuine vote" 
         src="${pageContext.request.contextPath}/static/images/rating/emptyUpvote.png"
         height="20" width="20">
```

The expected result should ignore the static url but instead it calls unread().

Comment: Use the different parameters on the `@ControllerAdvice` annotation to limit what to match.

Comment: Can you kindly give an example, I tried adding (annotations = GetMapping.class) to the  @ControllerAdvice and it simply blocked all requests.

Comment: Use the `packages` or `basePackages` attributes to limit this to only controller you defined in your packages.